# Is the set of points where two functions agree a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $M, N$ be smooth manifolds, $f : M \to N$ a smooth submersion and $g : M \to N$ a smooth function. Is it true that $R = \{x \in M\ |\ f(x) = g(x)\}$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$? How about if both $f, g$ are submersions?

I tried to show that the map $(f, g) : M \to N \times N$ is transverse to the diagonal $\Delta \subset M \times M$, but I can't see it. Am I going crazy here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that $R$ is necessarily a manifold, even if $g$ is a submersion.  Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the usual projection map onto the first coordinate, $f(x,y) = x$, which is definitely a submersion.

Suppose $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $g(x,y) = xy$.  Then $R$ consists of all those points with $xy = x$, that is, with $x(y-1) = 0$.  This is a union of the $y$-axis together with the horizontal line $y = 1$.  In particular, $R$ is not a manifold at the point $(0,1)$.

Now, $g$ is not a submersion because the differential $dg$ at the point $(0,0)$ is not surjective.  However, $g$ is a submersion on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.  So, if you restrict $f$ and $g$ to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$, then $R$ is still not a manifold, but $f$ and $g$ are submersions.

Comment: Examples get even crazier.  Draw a smooth vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is $0$ on the coordinate axis and points outward at all other points.  The flow of this vector field  for some fixed time is a diffeomorphism which agrees with identity map on the coordinate axes only.  Here, your $f$ and $g$ are even more than submersions - they are diffeomorphisms.

Comment: Yes, this does fail rather terribly. It happens that I was confused though -- the (true) statement which I wanted to use was that for a submersion $f : A \to M$ and a smooth $g : B \to M$, the set $\{(a, b) \in A \times B\ |\ f(a) = g(b)\}$ is an embedded submanifold of $A \times B$. This can indeed be proved by a transversality with the diagonal argument.

Comment: @Pedro:  Yes, that seems believable.